# Filling a ListView with an ImageList using View.Details

Tags: c#, .net, listview, imagelist, detailview

Having an issue loading icons in to my listview. I can get the images to work in large view but not in details, not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

```
private void CreateList()
{
    listView1.View = View.Details;

    listView1.Columns.Add("Icon", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Center);

    listView1.Columns.Add("Name", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

    imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);

    for (int i = 0; i < subKeys.Length; i++)
    {
        if (subKeys[i].Contains("App"))
        {
            imagePath = subKeys[i];

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagePath))
            {
                imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(imagePath));
            }

            numberOfImages++;
        }
    }

    listView1.StateImageList = this.imageList1;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
listView1.StateImageList = this.imageList1;
```

To

```
listView1.SmallImageList = this.imageList1;
```

And make sure that you are setting the `ImageIndex`, or `ImageKey` properties for each ListItem.

```
listItem.ImageIndex = 0; // or,
listItem.ImageKey = "myImage";
```

Comment: ah doesn't work for me :( Might be a problem with something else I am doing though :P

Comment: Make sure you are setting the image key/index, updated answer.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Had to uncomment my for method and it worked first go, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\myPicutures"); //change and get your folder
        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
                this.imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
            }
            catch{
                Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
            }
        }
        this.listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
        this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);
        this.listView1.LargeImageList = this.imageList1;
        //or
        //this.listView1.View = View.SmallIcon;
        //this.listView1.SmallImageList = this.imageList1;

        for (int j = 0; j < this.imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.ImageIndex = j;
            this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

You can even add 2nd column, and "add" a file name.

Comment: the string array contains a specific list of paths, so I could not use a directory like that :P The problem with the rest of your method is I need this for a listView.View = View.Detail; Also I believe I have seen the code you posted on stackoverflow when searching for similar issues, you should probably reference where you got it from :P